# how to prove that a grammar is LR(1) Theory of languages

Tags: compiler-construction

before parsing, how to know if a grammar is LR(1) or not ! thank
 you.

PS : I have looking around and I couldn find same question.

Comment: You might find more attention (and answers) on the [Computer Science StackExchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=LR%281%29).

Comment: Too broad, off topic, request for off-site resource, and *very* amply documented elsewhere, notably the Dragon book series. You might even want to look up the original Knuth paper: [*On the translation of languages from left to right*](http://www.dc.uba.ar/materias/tl/2010/c2/files/Knuth-1965-TranslationofLanguages.pdf) (1965).

Comment: Yes I have it already.. I will publish any informations I find ! I spend much time at this point, out teacher use his own theorems from his thesis. and that makes the mission hard for research !